# How to make sure (in compile-time) that collection wasn't reordered?

Tags: scala, scalaz, type-safety

Let's say I have indexed collection (`List` or `Map` doesn't matter here):

```
val zipped = List(1 -> "A", 3 -> "C", 8 -> "D")
```

It's hard to work with such (as every operation, like `map`, has to deal with `index`), so what I want to pass into business handler is:

```
case class Indexed[T](seq: Seq[T], i: Seq[Int])

val unzipped = Indexed(List("A", "C", "D"), List(1,3,8))

handler(unzipped.seq)
```

But I need user to be restricted, to do only `map`, `filter`, `collect`, `contains`, `forall`, `scanLeft` and so on. But not `flatMap` (except `filter`-like), `sort`, `++` and so forth. So any bijection/surjection, but not injection-like. In a pinch, user can live without `filter`/`flatMap`, so having `Functor`, but not `Monad` could be fine for me - anyway acceptable `List[Option[T]] => List[T]` from my original requirements isn't complete `Monad` (`M[M[T]] => M[T]`, `T => M[T]`).

`toList`, `toSet` are acceptable, but I also want to be sure that returning (from business handler) collection is based on original one. I can do this by adding path-dependent `Tag` (path-dependent type) to the type signature of original collection and require same-tagged collection as a return type (which can be cheated only with `asInstanceOf`). My first requirements can be satisfied by implementing my own `Traversable`.

So my own "wheel" to solve this is just a wrapper (with only subset of operations permitted + tags for making sure that collection is same):

```
 trait NonReorderedListT {
     trait Tag
 }

 trait NonReorderedList[Tg <: NonReorderedListT#Tag, T] {
   type Tag = Tg 
   def map[U](f: T => U): NonReorderedList[Tag, U] //same tag
   //... other permitted operations should be here        
 }


 object NonReorderedList {

   class NonReorderedListImpl[Tg <: NonReorderedListT#Tag, T] private[NonReorderedList] (l: List[T]) extends NonReorderedList[Tg, T] { 
      def map[U](f: T => U) = new NonReorderedListImpl[Tag, U](l.map(f))
      //... other permitted operations should be here  
   }     


   def apply[T](l: List[T]) = {
     val tagC = new NonReorderedListT {} //container
     new NonReorderedListImpl[tagC.Tag, T](l)
   }
 }
```

Here is the results from Scala REPL:

```
defined trait NonReorderedListT
defined trait NonReorderedList
defined class NonReorderedListImpl
defined object NonReorderedList

scala>  val l = NonReorderedList(List(1,2,3))
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
l: NonReorderedListImpl[tagC.Tag,Int] forSome { val tagC: NonReorderedListT } = NonReorderedListImpl@3620eab

scala> val res: NonReorderedList[l.Tag, Int] = l.map(_ + 1)
res: NonReorderedList[l.Tag,Int] = NonReorderedListImpl@34bddf43

scala>  val m = NonReorderedList(List(1,2,3))
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
m: NonReorderedListImpl[tagC.Tag,Int] forSome { val tagC: NonReorderedListT } = NonReorderedListImpl@2d8c729f

scala> val res: NonReorderedList[l.Tag, Int] = m.map(_ + 1)
<console>:31: error: type mismatch;
 found   : NonReorderedListImpl[m.Tag,Int]
    (which expands to)  NonReorderedListImpl[tagC.Tag,Int]
 required: NonReorderedList[l.Tag,Int]
    (which expands to)  NonReorderedList[tagC.Tag,Int]
       val res: NonReorderedList[l.Tag, Int] = m.map(_ + 1)
                                                    ^
```

However, it shouldn't be so rare situation when you need such collection, so maybe Scalaz already has some implementation, something like `NonEmptylist`, but `NonReorderedList`.

I'm doing all this because I have one already ordered collection (1 -> "A", 2 - "B", 3 -> "C", 4 -> "D", 5 -> "E") as an input, which splits into (1 -> "A", 3 -> "C", 4 -> "D") and (2 -> "B", 5 -> "E"), they're processed separately and then merged back (original order should be preserved). Ordering with complex predicate takes some time (as it calls to the external service), so I can't just reorder collection twice with it - second reordering should be based on simple index.

P.S. I'm not looking for less type-safe alternatives as I already have such in my project :). My goal is to improve existing (in my project) code.

Comment: OK, I'm probably missing something blindingly obvious... If I need to keep the user from messing with my data representation then I hide it in a class and make public only permitted operations.

Comment: @jwvh if you read more carefully - you'll find out that that's what I did + several other steps to ensure that user won't create another collection. Of course, I could close constructor, but actually I'm user of the library as well and still want to have ability to create collection, but make sure that it wasn't replaced with another one. So I also did some steps for that (see above) and it works. My question is: is it already implemented in scalaz or somewhere else as probably lot of people want to prevent users from reordering, so I don't want to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could be approached by using `Nat` and `HList` from shapeless? The idea is to model an element's index explicitly. (I asked a related question [Achieving compile safe indexing with Shapeless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328854/achieving-compile-safe-indexing-with-shapeless).) For example,

```
import shapeless._
import Nat._

case class Entry[+N<:Nat](value: String, index: N)

val send: Entry[ _1] :: Entry[ _3] :: Entry[ _4] :: HNil= Entry("A", _1):: Entry("C", _3) :: Entry("D", _4) :: HNil
val keep= Entry("B", _2) :: Entry("E", _5)  :: HNil
```

This would provide some type safety (although I'm not sure about the performance implications.)

Comment: +1 I like the idea of using `Nat` and performance of HList itself doesn't matter to me; however, one practical problem is that it would be nice to hide indices and concatenations in my case - it's so easy to let's say `Entry("Z", _1) :: keep` or write a function polymorphic on N like `.map(_.copy(index = _3))`. P.S. As a matter of fact, I left that project 3 years ago, and from what I've heard, my `NonReorderedList` seemed to survive 'til now, but my shapeless code (HLists and natural transformations) definitely didn't :).

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Thanks for the long-term perspective on the use of HLists - I've realised that I should really isolate the shapeless bits in my code.