# Achieving compile safe indexing with Shapeless

Tags: scala, types, shapeless

*Problem:*   Let   `val v = List(0.5, 1.2, 0.3)` model a realisation of some vector  ***v*** = (v_1, v_2, v_3). The index *j* in *v_j* is implied by the element's position in the list. A lot of boilerplate and bugs have been due to tracking these indices, eg, when creating modified lists from the original. ([How to make sure (in compile-time) that collection wasn't reordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802175/how-to-make-sure-in-compile-time-that-collection-wasnt-reordered) seems related.)

*General question:* What could be a good way to ensure correct indexing at compile time? (I assume that performance is not essential.)

My plan is to use subclasses of  `Nat` in shapeless to model the indices as (explicit) types. The current solution is

```
import shapeless._
import Nat._

trait Elem[+A, +N<:Nat]{
    val v: A
    val ind: N}

case class DecElem[N<:Nat](v: BigDecimal, ind: N) extends Elem[BigDecimal, N]

object Decimals {
type One = DecElem[ _0]:: HNil
type Two =  DecElem[ _0]:: DecElem[_1] :: HNil
//...
}
case class Scalar(v: Decimals.One)
case class VecTwo(v: Decimals.Two)
```

This, however, gets tedious in larger dimensions. 
Another question is how to approach the generic case in `trait Elem[+A, +N<:Nat]`. As a start, I defined `case class ElemVector[A, M<:Nat](vs: Sized[List[Elem[A, Nat]], M])`, which  loses the specific index type  in `Elem`. What might be a strategy to circumvent this difficulty?

(Note: A better design may be to wrap  `List[A]` by attaching explicit indices and deal with wrapper class. This, however, does not essentially change the question.)

**UPDATE** Here's is a trivial illustration of accidental swapping of vector elements.

```
import shapeless.Nat._
import shapeless.{Sized, nat}

type VectorTwo = Sized[IndexedSeq[Double], nat._2]

val f = (p: VectorTwo, x: Double) => {
  val V = p(_0)
  val K = p(_1)

  V * x/(K + x)
}

val V : Double = 500
val K : Double = 1

val correct: VectorTwo = Sized(V, K)
val wrong: VectorTwo = Sized(K, V)  //Compiles!


f(correct, 10)  // = 454.54
f(wrong, 10)    // =   0.02
```

I'd like to enlist the compiler to prevent such errors in vectors with many elements, and wonder if there could be an elegant solution with Shapeless.

Comment: Why is `shapeless.Sized` not enough for you?

Comment: Suppose you have a mathematical model with a parameter vector. The index of each vector element is meaningful, and it's easy to plug in the wrong element into the model. Another use case is  math optimisation where you must select a subset of elements from the original vector, and need to refer back each selected element to another indexed entry. Another is when users specify individual vector elements through GUI.

Comment: These are use cases for collection with statically known size. Could you be more specific what you'd like to achieve that can't be done with `Sized`?

Comment: I'll update the question with some code example

Comment: We can use `HList` and types instead of raw `Double`s: `case class K(value: Double); case class V(value: Double); val lst: K :: V :: HNil = K(1.0) :: V(500.0) :: HNil`.

Comment: Yes, that's kind of similar to what I've been doing. The problem is if there are 100 - 200 parameters, then the definitions of  HList types will get quite long. Maybe it's possible to define such types recursively.